# Moving code from Android's MainActivity class to their own Library or File

Tags: android, android-library

I am new to Java & Android development, but I have been able to create a mess of functions, subclasses & constants that work perfectly fine when pasted inside the `MainActivity` class of a default Android project.

The purpose of these functions is to "ping home" to let my servers know when an application install has occurred. The only code that is needed to make this happen is the line `notifyMyServer()` inside this standard block of code of `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        notifyMyServer("install"); /* Notify MyServer of an Installation */

    }
}
```

Pasting the functions, subclass, constants and imports that make `notifyMyServer()` work directly inside the `MainActivity.java` file seems dirty to me. I would love to be able to move them to their own file and/or library so I could drag & drop that file into other apps I want to do perform the same tracking on.

**How is this typically done?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your notify code and create an class which just performs this notification (can be part of a library or not):

```
public class NotifyingActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        notifyMyServer("install"); /* Notify MyServer of an Installation */
    }
}
```

And then in your MainActivity, just inherit from `NotifyingActivity` instead of `Activity`. Then the notification will automatically happen when you call super.onCreate() inside of MainActivity.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I did that but I am now getting a lot of NullPointerExceptions when trying to run it.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two ways to solve this:

1) Create a `NotifyActivity` class which can be extended by `MainActivity`, as described in [@Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167033/moving-code-from-androids-mainactivity-class-to-their-own-library-or-file/13168030#13168030). This uses inheritence.

2) Create a `NotifyServer` class and create an instance of it inside of `MainActivity`, either as a class variable or as a local variable in `onCreate()`. This uses composition.

Generally in Object Oriented Design, composition is preferred over inheritence. I strongly suggest that you learn about both of these concepts as you will use them over and over in your Java programming.